# Flutter : Getting Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: when using local graddle file location

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, native

I am trying to build apk using local gradle version, however I am getting below error.

```
[ +607 ms] Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\abcuser\.gradle\wrapper\dists\C:UsersabcuserDownloadsgradle-8.6-rc-1-bin\8es7ikj1sxv2vjnincg74o1de\C:UsersabcuserDownloadsgradle-8.6-rc-1-bin.zip.lck
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
[   +5 ms]      at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:344)
[        ]      at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
[        ]      at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:213)
[        ]      at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:49)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
[        ]      at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
[   +4 ms]      at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[  +46 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 1,175ms)
[   +5 ms] [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
```

gradle-wrapper.properties file path:

```
distributionUrl=file\:///C:\Users\abcuser\Downloads\gradle-8.6-rc-1-bin.zip
```

.gradle wrapper location : I have also tried to remove this folder and build but no luck. Also, copied the gradle-8.6-rc-1-bin.zip file into below path but no luck.

```
C:\Users\abcuser\.gradle\wrapper\dists
```

Also, tried to remove the file gradle-wrapper.jar from the project but no luck.

Can you please help to resolve this issue?